# Find item that is in one of two arrays - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have, problem how to find an item that is listed in one of arrays and do something.
I need to do different things depending on what is the variable.
I tried a for loop in other for loop but it search only the first element of each array.

```js
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var array2 = ['d','e','f'];

var name = 'e';
    for (i=0;i<array1.length;i++) {
        if(name==array1[i]) {
          //do something
        } else {
          for (i=0;i<array2.length;i++){
              if(name==array2[i]) {
                //do something 2
              } else {
                console.log("error");
              }
          }
       }
    }
```

name variable is defined by user

Comment: if you using "i" for one for loop, use some other letter for nested one like "j"

Comment: in both the for loops, you loop over the `i` variables. which means that every outer-loop, you reset it back to 0 on the inner-loop, then loop over that array until `array2.length`. Then it goes back to the outer-loop, after which `i` is `array1.length`, and it will exit that loop.

Comment: Do you really want to search the second array for every non-matching element in the first array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` method in javascript.

```
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var array2 = ['d','e','f'];

var name = 'e';
if (array1.indexOf(name) != -1) {
    //do something
} else if (array2.indexOf(name) != -1) {
    //do something 2
} else {
    console.log("error");
}
```

For more information see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Answer (score 4):

this is an easy one with some fancy new functions:

```
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var array2 = ['d','e','f'];

var name = 'e';
// use && if it has to be in both arrays
// use || if it has to be in either of the arrays
if (array1.includes(name) || array2.includes(name)) {
  // do fancy things!
}
```

you'll need a polyfill for internet explorer though: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

## edit

so when you have to do two different actions when depending in which array, it's basically this:

```
if (array1.includes(name)) {
   // do this
} else if (array2.includes(name)) {
   // do this
}
```

Comment: I think it was an else based on his requirement but this is definitely the way to go

Comment: Probably should be `||` not `&&`

Comment: It would actually be an if/else based on his requirement since he had to take a different action for each.

Comment: You can also have a much simpler polyfill if you don't care about the second param. You can just create a polyfill that calls indexOf

Comment: ah yeah, you are both correct. i misread the title as "find an item that is in two arrays" :-) fixing it now!

Comment: that's actually not the title and neither it is in his description. but i've appended it... I hope thought that, since we're not a homework-assignment-medium, someone can work his way toward that code by copying the same line and removing one of the two statements ;-)

Comment: won't work in my case, I need to do different thing depending from the array.

Comment: it's why i included the answer to your problem as well. anyhow, glad your problem is solved. Too bad you accepted the other answer since they introduced the `includes` function for this use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var array2 = ['d','e','f'];

var name = 'e';

var bothArraysContainName = (arrayOne, arrayTwo, name) => {
  var resOne = arrayOne.filter( (val) => val === name)
  var resTwo = arrayTwo.filter( (val) => val === name)
  return resOne.length > 0 && resTwo.length > 0
}

console.log(bothArraysContainName(array1, array2, name));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array1 = ['a','b','c'];
var array2 = ['d','e','f'];

var name = 'e';
array1.concat(array2).forEach(function(item) {
    if(item === name) {
        //do your stuff here
    }
};
```

or,

```
const result = array1.concat(array2).filter(item => item === name);
if(result.length > 0)
    //do your stuff
else
    // return an error
```

result is now an array which can be either empty or contains one elem.
you can do your test on result and do your stuff.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `[].indexOf()`
Like this:

```
if(array1.indexOf(name) == -1){
 if(array2.indexOf(name) == -1){
  Console.log("not found");
 } else { /*Found in array2*/ }
} else {
/*Found in array1*/
}
```

Comment: Why no. Forgive any syntax errors, I'm typing on a mobile phone.

Comment: Well, your code should be runnable. I said because it had so many typo and  errors. You should take time to make your answer 100% correct before you offer it to anyone. IMO.

Comment: Agree. I should have took some more time. But I thought I was offering concept instead of code.